# Sort JSON result by value inside an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, wikipedia

I'm looking to use the API of Wikipedia to get places around my location.

So i tried : 
[That request](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=coordinates%7Cpageimages%7Cpageterms&colimit=50&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=500&pilimit=50&wbptterms=description&generator=geosearch&ggscoord=50.417073%7C4.462617&ggsradius=1000&ggslimit=50&format=json&codistancefrompoint=50.417073%7C4.462617)
But i get result sort by pageID and not distance.
How can i do in Javascript with the sort command?

Thank you for you help ;-)
Alexis

Comment: Or if someone can explain me how to sort with javascript ?  Because i don't know how to sort by value inside another array.

Comment: u want to sort by pageid or dist value

Comment: i would love by dist value

Comment: please put your input array in question.

Comment: sorry? i didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data =[{
 "batchcomplete": "",
 "query": {
  "pages": {
   "1052923": {
    "pageid": 1052923,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Stade du Pays de Charleroi",
    "index": 0,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.4146503,
      "lon": 4.4537527,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 683.4
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ca/Charleroi_Stade_du_Pays_de_Charleroi_1.jpg/500px-Charleroi_Stade_du_Pays_de_Charleroi_1.jpg",
     "width": 500,
     "height": 288
    }
   },
   "1237678": {
    "pageid": 1237678,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Chet (métro de Charleroi)",
    "index": 1,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.410417,
      "lon": 4.464397,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 750.8
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/MLC-chet.jpg",
     "width": 500,
     "height": 375
    },
    "terms": {
     "description": [
      "station du métro de Charleroi (Belgique)"
     ]
    }
   },
   "1237691": {
    "pageid": 1237691,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Neuville (métro de Charleroi)",
    "index": 2,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.414637,
      "lon": 4.458818,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 381.9
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/MLC-neuville.jpg",
     "width": 500,
     "height": 375
    },
    "terms": {
     "description": [
      "station du métro de Charleroi (Belgique)"
     ]
    }
   },
   "1241539": {
    "pageid": 1241539,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Waterloo (métro de Charleroi)",
    "index": 3,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.4175,
      "lon": 4.45,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 895.2
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/29/Waterloo_metro_station_%28Charleroi%29_-_01.jpg/500px-Waterloo_metro_station_%28Charleroi%29_-_01.jpg",
     "width": 500,
     "height": 331
    },
    "terms": {
     "description": [
      "station du métro de Charleroi (Belgique)"
     ]
    }
   },
   "1264919": {
    "pageid": 1264919,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Samaritaine (métro de Charleroi)",
    "index": 4,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.42,
      "lon": 4.461389,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 336.9
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Samaritaine_metro_station_%28Charleroi%29_-_01.jpg/500px-Samaritaine_metro_station_%28Charleroi%29_-_01.jpg",
     "width": 500,
     "height": 331
    },
    "terms": {
     "description": [
      "station du métro de Charleroi (Belgique)"
     ]
    }
   },
   "1264973": {
    "pageid": 1264973,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Gazomètre (métro de Charleroi)",
    "index": 5,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.421944,
      "lon": 4.473889,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 965
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Charleroi_OSM_map.svg/374px-Charleroi_OSM_map.svg.png",
     "width": 374,
     "height": 500
    },
    "terms": {
     "description": [
      "station du métro de Charleroi (Belgique)"
     ]
    }
   },
   "1269274": {
    "pageid": 1269274,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Janson (métro de Charleroi)",
    "index": 6,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.413056,
      "lon": 4.451944,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 878.3
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Janson_Metro_Station%2C_Charleroi_05.JPG/500px-Janson_Metro_Station%2C_Charleroi_05.JPG",
     "width": 500,
     "height": 281
    },
    "terms": {
     "description": [
      "station du métro de Charleroi (Belgique)"
     ]
    }
   },
   "3924344": {
    "pageid": 3924344,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Liste des rues de Charleroi",
    "index": 7,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.417556,
      "lon": 4.450976,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 826.5
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Map_Charleroi_in_Charleroi.svg/500px-Map_Charleroi_in_Charleroi.svg.png",
     "width": 500,
     "height": 492
    },
    "terms": {
     "description": [
      "page de liste de Wikipédia"
     ]
    }
   },
   "5819249": {
    "pageid": 5819249,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Tour Bleue",
    "index": 8,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.412,
      "lon": 4.45364,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 850.2
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Charleroi_-_Tour_bleue_-_2015-01-31.jpg/331px-Charleroi_-_Tour_bleue_-_2015-01-31.jpg",
     "width": 331,
     "height": 500
    }
   },
   "6234241": {
    "pageid": 6234241,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Square Jules Hiernaux",
    "index": 9,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.417556,
      "lon": 4.450976,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 826.5
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/Charleroi_-_Universit%C3%A9_du_Travail_-_Vigie.JPG/500px-Charleroi_-_Universit%C3%A9_du_Travail_-_Vigie.JPG",
     "width": 500,
     "height": 375
    },
    "terms": {
     "description": [
      "place de Charleroi, Belgique"
     ]
    }
   },
   "6470845": {
    "pageid": 6470845,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Maison des médecins",
    "index": 10,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.415102,
      "lon": 4.449836,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 931.7
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/Charleroi_-_maison_des_m%C3%A9decins_-_02.jpg/289px-Charleroi_-_maison_des_m%C3%A9decins_-_02.jpg",
     "width": 289,
     "height": 500
    },
    "terms": {
     "description": [
      "maison Art nouveau à Charleroi"
     ]
    }
   },
   "7696487": {
    "pageid": 7696487,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Porte de Waterloo ou de la Belle Alliance de Charleroi",
    "index": 11,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.422794,
      "lon": 4.466356,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 689.1
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Montignies-sur-Sambre_-_Porte_de_Waterloo.jpg/375px-Montignies-sur-Sambre_-_Porte_de_Waterloo.jpg",
     "width": 375,
     "height": 500
    }
   },
   "8848501": {
    "pageid": 8848501,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Caserne Defeld",
    "index": 12,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.412008,
      "lon": 4.453642,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 849.5
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Charleroi_-_Bd_Mayence_-_Caserne_Defeld_-_portail.jpg/500px-Charleroi_-_Bd_Mayence_-_Caserne_Defeld_-_portail.jpg",
     "width": 500,
     "height": 375
    },
    "terms": {
     "description": [
      "ancienne caserne de la gendarmerie à Charleroi"
     ]
    }
   },
   "10059120": {
    "pageid": 10059120,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Maternité reine Astrid",
    "index": 13,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.415,
      "lon": 4.45194444,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 790.6
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Charleroi_-_Porte_de_Waterloo_et_Bd_Dewandre_en_1937.jpg/500px-Charleroi_-_Porte_de_Waterloo_et_Bd_Dewandre_en_1937.jpg",
     "width": 500,
     "height": 242
    },
    "terms": {
     "description": [
      "ancien hôpital de Charleroi"
     ]
    }
   },
   "10190333": {
    "pageid": 10190333,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Attentat du 6 août 2016 à Charleroi",
    "index": 14,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.412,
      "lon": 4.45364,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 850.2
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Charleroi_-_Tour_bleue_-_2015-01-31.jpg/331px-Charleroi_-_Tour_bleue_-_2015-01-31.jpg",
     "width": 331,
     "height": 500
    }
   },
   "10469222": {
    "pageid": 10469222,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Échangeur de Charleroi-Nord",
    "index": 15,
    "coordinates": [
     {
      "lat": 50.4176,
      "lon": 4.4561,
      "primary": "",
      "globe": "earth",
      "dist": 465.4
     }
    ],
    "thumbnail": {
     "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Charleroi_-_R9_-_portes_de_Waterloo_et_de_Fleurus.jpg/500px-Charleroi_-_R9_-_portes_de_Waterloo_et_de_Fleurus.jpg",
     "width": 500,
     "height": 375
    },
    "terms": {
     "description": [
      "échangeur autoroutier belge"
     ]
    }
   }
  }
 }
}];
//alert(data);
//console.table(data);
function sortByKey(jsObj){
   var sortedArray = [];

   // Push each JSON Object entry in array by [key, value]
   for(var i in jsObj)
   {
  sortedArray.push([i, jsObj[i]]);
 }

 // Run native sort function and returns sorted array.
 return sortedArray.sort();
}
 var sortedbyKeyJSONArray = '';
       $.each(data, function (i, item) {
         sortedbyKeyJSONArray = sortByKey(item.query.pages);
         sortByKey(item.query.pages);
          // console.table(item.query.pages);
            //console.table(sortedbyKeyJSONArray);
       });
       console.table(sortedbyKeyJSONArray);
//var sortedbyKeyJSONArray = sortByKey(data.query.pages.coordinates.dist);
//console.table(data);
/*data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});*/
//document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data={"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"1052923":{"pageid":1052923,"ns":0,"title":"Stade du Pays de Charleroi","index":0,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.4146503,"lon":4.4537527,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":683.4}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ca/Charleroi_Stade_du_Pays_de_Charleroi_1.jpg/500px-Charleroi_Stade_du_Pays_de_Charleroi_1.jpg","width":500,"height":288}},"1237678":{"pageid":1237678,"ns":0,"title":"Chet (m\u00e9tro de Charleroi)","index":1,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.410417,"lon":4.464397,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":750.8}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/MLC-chet.jpg","width":500,"height":375},"terms":{"description":["station du m\u00e9tro de Charleroi (Belgique)"]}},"1237691":{"pageid":1237691,"ns":0,"title":"Neuville (m\u00e9tro de Charleroi)","index":2,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.414637,"lon":4.458818,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":381.9}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/MLC-neuville.jpg","width":500,"height":375},"terms":{"description":["station du m\u00e9tro de Charleroi (Belgique)"]}},"1241539":{"pageid":1241539,"ns":0,"title":"Waterloo (m\u00e9tro de Charleroi)","index":3,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.4175,"lon":4.45,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":895.2}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/29/Waterloo_metro_station_%28Charleroi%29_-_01.jpg/500px-Waterloo_metro_station_%28Charleroi%29_-_01.jpg","width":500,"height":331},"terms":{"description":["station du m\u00e9tro de Charleroi (Belgique)"]}},"1264919":{"pageid":1264919,"ns":0,"title":"Samaritaine (m\u00e9tro de Charleroi)","index":4,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.42,"lon":4.461389,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":336.9}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Samaritaine_metro_station_%28Charleroi%29_-_01.jpg/500px-Samaritaine_metro_station_%28Charleroi%29_-_01.jpg","width":500,"height":331},"terms":{"description":["station du m\u00e9tro de Charleroi (Belgique)"]}},"1264973":{"pageid":1264973,"ns":0,"title":"Gazom\u00e8tre (m\u00e9tro de Charleroi)","index":5,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.421944,"lon":4.473889,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":965}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Charleroi_OSM_map.svg/374px-Charleroi_OSM_map.svg.png","width":374,"height":500},"terms":{"description":["station du m\u00e9tro de Charleroi (Belgique)"]}},"1269274":{"pageid":1269274,"ns":0,"title":"Janson (m\u00e9tro de Charleroi)","index":6,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.413056,"lon":4.451944,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":878.3}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Janson_Metro_Station%2C_Charleroi_05.JPG/500px-Janson_Metro_Station%2C_Charleroi_05.JPG","width":500,"height":281},"terms":{"description":["station du m\u00e9tro de Charleroi (Belgique)"]}},"3924344":{"pageid":3924344,"ns":0,"title":"Liste des rues de Charleroi","index":7,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.417556,"lon":4.450976,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":826.5}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Map_Charleroi_in_Charleroi.svg/500px-Map_Charleroi_in_Charleroi.svg.png","width":500,"height":492},"terms":{"description":["page de liste de Wikip\u00e9dia"]}},"5819249":{"pageid":5819249,"ns":0,"title":"Tour Bleue","index":8,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.412,"lon":4.45364,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":850.2}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Charleroi_-_Tour_bleue_-_2015-01-31.jpg/331px-Charleroi_-_Tour_bleue_-_2015-01-31.jpg","width":331,"height":500}},"6234241":{"pageid":6234241,"ns":0,"title":"Square Jules Hiernaux","index":9,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.417556,"lon":4.450976,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":826.5}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/Charleroi_-_Universit%C3%A9_du_Travail_-_Vigie.JPG/500px-Charleroi_-_Universit%C3%A9_du_Travail_-_Vigie.JPG","width":500,"height":375},"terms":{"description":["place de Charleroi, Belgique"]}},"6470845":{"pageid":6470845,"ns":0,"title":"Maison des m\u00e9decins","index":10,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.415102,"lon":4.449836,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":931.7}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/Charleroi_-_maison_des_m%C3%A9decins_-_02.jpg/289px-Charleroi_-_maison_des_m%C3%A9decins_-_02.jpg","width":289,"height":500},"terms":{"description":["maison Art nouveau \u00e0 Charleroi"]}},"7696487":{"pageid":7696487,"ns":0,"title":"Porte de Waterloo ou de la Belle Alliance de Charleroi","index":11,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.422794,"lon":4.466356,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":689.1}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Montignies-sur-Sambre_-_Porte_de_Waterloo.jpg/375px-Montignies-sur-Sambre_-_Porte_de_Waterloo.jpg","width":375,"height":500}},"8848501":{"pageid":8848501,"ns":0,"title":"Caserne Defeld","index":12,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.412008,"lon":4.453642,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":849.5}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Charleroi_-_Bd_Mayence_-_Caserne_Defeld_-_portail.jpg/500px-Charleroi_-_Bd_Mayence_-_Caserne_Defeld_-_portail.jpg","width":500,"height":375},"terms":{"description":["ancienne caserne de la gendarmerie \u00e0 Charleroi"]}},"10059120":{"pageid":10059120,"ns":0,"title":"Maternit\u00e9 reine Astrid","index":13,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.415,"lon":4.45194444,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":790.6}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Charleroi_-_Porte_de_Waterloo_et_Bd_Dewandre_en_1937.jpg/500px-Charleroi_-_Porte_de_Waterloo_et_Bd_Dewandre_en_1937.jpg","width":500,"height":242},"terms":{"description":["ancien h\u00f4pital de Charleroi"]}},"10190333":{"pageid":10190333,"ns":0,"title":"Attentat du 6 ao\u00fbt 2016 \u00e0 Charleroi","index":14,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.412,"lon":4.45364,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":850.2}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Charleroi_-_Tour_bleue_-_2015-01-31.jpg/331px-Charleroi_-_Tour_bleue_-_2015-01-31.jpg","width":331,"height":500}},"10469222":{"pageid":10469222,"ns":0,"title":"\u00c9changeur de Charleroi-Nord","index":15,"coordinates":[{"lat":50.4176,"lon":4.4561,"primary":"","globe":"earth","dist":465.4}],"thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Charleroi_-_R9_-_portes_de_Waterloo_et_de_Fleurus.jpg/500px-Charleroi_-_R9_-_portes_de_Waterloo_et_de_Fleurus.jpg","width":500,"height":375},"terms":{"description":["\u00e9changeur autoroutier belge"]}}}}
         };

var pagesKeys=Object.keys(data.query.pages);

var pagesArray=pagesKeys.map(function(d){
  return data.query.pages[d];
});

pagesArray=pagesArray.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.coordinates[0].dist - b.coordinates[0].dist;
});
console.log("Sorted Data based on Distance:"+pagesArray);
```

Comment: but dude after the sort working fine after this sort the above data array is changes right pages and page id are mis place .

Comment: I think no Please try it in console.